# How can change the source of one of many images when the mouse is on it in using one function?

Tags: javascript

I have five images, I try to change the source of any of them when the mouse is on it, the problem is that only first image will change when I hover it but the other not, How can I solve it

```
var img1 = document.querySelector("#image1");
var img2 = document.querySelector("#image2");
var img3 = document.querySelector("#image3");
var img4 = document.querySelector("#image4");
var img5 = document.querySelector("#image5");

var change_images = function(){

  if(img1){
   img1.src = "images/image1_2.jpg";
  }
  else if(img2){
   img2.src = "images/image2_2.jpg";
  }
  else if(img3){
   img3.src = "images/image3_2.jpg";
  }
  else if(img4){
   img4.src = "images/image4_2.jpg";   
  }
  else if(img5){
   img5.src = "images/image5_2.jpg";
 }
}

img1.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images);
img2.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images);
img3.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images);
img4.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images);
img5.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images);
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to add `e` to the argument list of the handler, and then check if the hovered image (e.target) is one of the images in the variables. A more advanced way would be to use event delegation, i.e. defining only a single listener to a parent element of the images.

Comment: I totally forgot the properties of `e`, which is why I suggested a more contrived solution. I like this better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna extract the hovering locic into a function

```
 function hoverChange(selector, src){
   const img = document.querySelector(selector);
   const orig = img.src;

   img.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
     img.src = src;
   });

   img.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
     img.src = orig;
   });
}
```

So you can do this:

```
 window.onload = () => {
   hoverChange("#image1", "picture2.png");
   //...
 };
```

---

Note that your code does not work because:

```
  if(img1){
```

`img1` is an object, it is therefore *truthy* and it will always enter the first block. You might wanna take the event passed to your function:

```
 var change_images = function(event){
```

And then compare the events target to the image:

```
 if(img1 === event.target)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add an argument to your function calls, like so:

```
img1.addEventListener("mouseover",change_images(1));
```

Then change your check in your function to check for the int you pass in:

```
var change_images = function(i) {

    if (i === 1) {
        img1.src = "images/image1_2.jpg";
    }
    else if (i === 2) {
        img2.src = "images/image2_2.jpg";
    // etc.
}
```

This is a simple solution, but doesn't address your question of how to get the source.

Comment: Indeed, that way nothing would work ... Learn the difference between function call and function reference.

Comment: This is far away from being a good answer. You should definetly provide the curried version of change_images that takes a number as a parameter as that is neccessary for your oneliner to work.

Comment: @Teemu Sorry, is that wrong, should it just be `function change_images(i) { ... };` ?